# Table positioning problem between two paragraph

Tags: tables

I have designed a long table, the problem is that this table is displayed in the bottom of the document and even when a paragraph is set to be displayed after the table it's displayed before the table.  I have also used [!ht] to maintain the table where I want but it didn't seem to influence on it.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
%%\usepackage{caption} % is loaded automatically by 'subcaption'
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
%%\usepackage{natbib} % is loaded automatically by elsarticle doc class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed}  % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

%% Load the next two packages *last*:
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction} 


 blablablablablablablablablablablablablabllabl\\blablablablabl\\
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{3}{C{0.45cm}} *{2}{C{1.69cm}} c c @{}} 
\toprule
Voltage N\textsuperscript{o} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Switching states} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Voltage output} & Magnitude & Phase \\   
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
$V_n$ & $S_a$ & $S_b$ & $S_c$ & $V_{\alpha}$ & $V_{\beta}$ & 
$U_{\mathrm{ref}}$ & $\alpha$ \\ 
\midrule
$V_{0o}$ & 0 & 0    & 0    & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{0p}$ & 1 & 1    & 1   & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{0n}$ &  -1 &  -1    & -1    & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{1p}$ & 1 & 0    & 0    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ 
& 0 \\
$V_{1n}$ & 0 & -1 & -1 & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0 
\\
$V_{2p}$ & 1 & 1    & 0    & $U_{dc}/6$ & $\sqrt{3}\,U_{dc}/6$ & $U_{dc}/3$ 
& $\pi/3$ \\
$V_{2n}$  &  0 &  0 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi/3$ \\
$V_{3p}$  &   0 & 1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi/3$ \\
$V_{3n}$  &   -1 &  0 &  -1 &  -$U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &   
$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi/3$ \\
$V_{4p}$  &   0 & 1 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &   $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{4n}$  &   -1 & 0 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &   $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{5p}$  &   0 &  0 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{5n}$  &   -1 &  -1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{6p}$  &   1 &  0 &  1 &  $U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{6n}$  &   0 &  -1 &  0 &  $U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{7}$  &   1 &  0 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/2 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/6 \\
$V_{8}$  &   0 &  1 &  -1 &  0 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ &  $\sqrt{3}$ 
$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/2 \\
$V_{9}$  &   -1 &  1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/2 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{10}$  &   -1 &  0 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/2 & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 7$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{11}$  &   0 &  -1 &  1 &  0 & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ &  $\sqrt{3}$ 
$U_{dc}$/3 & 3$\pi$/2 \\
$V_{12}$  &   1 &  -1 &  0 &  $U_{dc}$/2  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 11$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{13}$  &   1 &  -1 &  -1 &  2$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &  2 $U_{dc}$/3 & 0 \\
$V_{14}$  &   1 &  1 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/3  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/3 \\
$V_{15}$  &   -1 &  1 &  -1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{16}$  &   -1 &  1 &  1 &  -2$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 & 2$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{17}$  &   -1 &  -1 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{18}$  &   1 &  -1 &  1 &  $U_{dc}$/3  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 




  trtrtrtrtrtrtrtrtrtrttaatatatatatatatatat \\

\end{document}
```

here is the image [image]

Comment: this is just a repeat of the question you just asked

Comment: A modified question, I lose the control of the table position because of the length of the table. You can check the code  to verify.

Comment: the table clearly would not fit on the first page so it moves to the second, it is hard to guess what else you want but in any case this question is a duplicate. you should never use `[!h]` (the above document produces a warning about that,) use `[htp]` or perhaps you want `[H]` from the float package

Comment: No sorry there is no new detail here you could have edited the question you just asked but either way it is just a duplicate of the question on keeping the table from floating.

Comment: No this is not the what I want , the second paragraph where there is trtrtrtrtrtatata should appear after the table but it's shown before the table

Comment: the _only_ reason to put anything in a `table` environment is to allow latex to move the content to help with page breaking. If you do not want that just put the `tabular`  directly into the document not surrounded by `\begin{table}` then it will not move and you will get a horrible page break with white space.

Comment: You are right about it it works now after removing the table environment, the problem is that sometimes you can't let latex move the content because it may display a figure before a table while the table should appear before

Comment: no latex keeps all floats of the same type in sequence so if you have two items that should be kept in sequence they should be in the same float type.

Comment: The same type do you mean figure and figure or figure and table ?

Comment: yes or a new type (eg the float package lets you define new types) but in this example do you really want a two line paragraph then the rest of the page empty, then the table then the second paragraph on page 3? latex will not leave the page so short unless you force it. eg with `\clearpage` after the table.

Comment: Ah now it's clear but here is a complicated case: you have the table environment which is used and the figure environment which isn't used and you want the figure to be displayed after the table and of course there are some paragraphs after the floats. After compiling, the figure will be displayed before the table even if the environment figure isn't used

Comment: figures and tables are _floats_  they are not in the main document flow. so paragraphs that are in the main docuemnt flow are not before or after the figures, that is why floats have captions so they can be referenced indirectly, this has been how typesetters manage page breaking for centuries, it is not a latex invention.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your table fills the complete page!

To show this to you I added package `showframe` which visualized the resulting typing area and margins of your document. With package `blindtext` I added some dumy text to your code.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe,blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
%%\usepackage{caption} % is loaded automatically by 'subcaption'
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
%%\usepackage{natbib} % is loaded automatically by elsarticle doc class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed}  % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

%% Load the next two packages *last*:
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} 


 blablablablablablablablablablablablablabllabl\\blablablablabl\\
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{3}{C{0.45cm}} *{2}{C{1.69cm}} c c @{}} 
\toprule
Voltage N\textsuperscript{o} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Switching states} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Voltage output} & Magnitude & Phase \\   
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
$V_n$ & $S_a$ & $S_b$ & $S_c$ & $V_{\alpha}$ & $V_{\beta}$ & 
$U_{\mathrm{ref}}$ & $\alpha$ \\ 
\midrule
$V_{0o}$ & 0 & 0    & 0    & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{0p}$ & 1 & 1    & 1   & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{0n}$ &  -1 &  -1    & -1    & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{1p}$ & 1 & 0    & 0    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ 
& 0 \\
$V_{1n}$ & 0 & -1 & -1 & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0 
\\
$V_{2p}$ & 1 & 1    & 0    & $U_{dc}/6$ & $\sqrt{3}\,U_{dc}/6$ & $U_{dc}/3$ 
& $\pi/3$ \\
$V_{2n}$  &  0 &  0 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi/3$ \\
$V_{3p}$  &   0 & 1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi/3$ \\
$V_{3n}$  &   -1 &  0 &  -1 &  -$U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &   
$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi/3$ \\
$V_{4p}$  &   0 & 1 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &   $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{4n}$  &   -1 & 0 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &   $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{5p}$  &   0 &  0 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{5n}$  &   -1 &  -1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{6p}$  &   1 &  0 &  1 &  $U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{6n}$  &   0 &  -1 &  0 &  $U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{7}$  &   1 &  0 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/2 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/6 \\
$V_{8}$  &   0 &  1 &  -1 &  0 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ &  $\sqrt{3}$ 
$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/2 \\
$V_{9}$  &   -1 &  1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/2 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{10}$  &   -1 &  0 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/2 & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 7$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{11}$  &   0 &  -1 &  1 &  0 & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ &  $\sqrt{3}$ 
$U_{dc}$/3 & 3$\pi$/2 \\
$V_{12}$  &   1 &  -1 &  0 &  $U_{dc}$/2  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 11$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{13}$  &   1 &  -1 &  -1 &  2$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &  2 $U_{dc}$/3 & 0 \\
$V_{14}$  &   1 &  1 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/3  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/3 \\
$V_{15}$  &   -1 &  1 &  -1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{16}$  &   -1 &  1 &  1 &  -2$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 & 2$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{17}$  &   -1 &  -1 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{18}$  &   1 &  -1 &  1 &  $U_{dc}$/3  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

you get the following page with table, showing that it fills completely the page:

[image]

## EDIT:

With the following MWE your table is printed with `longtable` going over two pages:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe,blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable} % <==============================================
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
%%\usepackage{caption} % is loaded automatically by 'subcaption'
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
%%\usepackage{natbib} % is loaded automatically by elsarticle doc class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed}  % Framing contents
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

%% Load the next two packages *last*:
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} 


 blablablablablablablablablablablablablabllabl\\blablablablabl\\

\begin{longtable}{@{} c *{3}{C{0.45cm}} *{2}{C{1.69cm}} c c @{}} % <====================
\toprule
Voltage N\textsuperscript{o} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Switching states} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Voltage output} & Magnitude & Phase \\   
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
$V_n$ & $S_a$ & $S_b$ & $S_c$ & $V_{\alpha}$ & $V_{\beta}$ & 
$U_{\mathrm{ref}}$ & $\alpha$ \\ 
\midrule
$V_{0o}$ & 0 & 0    & 0    & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{0p}$ & 1 & 1    & 1   & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{0n}$ &  -1 &  -1    & -1    & 0 & 0                    & 0 & 0 \\
$V_{1p}$ & 1 & 0    & 0    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ 
& 0 \\
$V_{1n}$ & 0 & -1 & -1 & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0                    & $U_{dc}/3$ & 0 
\\
$V_{2p}$ & 1 & 1    & 0    & $U_{dc}/6$ & $\sqrt{3}\,U_{dc}/6$ & $U_{dc}/3$ 
& $\pi/3$ \\
$V_{2n}$  &  0 &  0 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi/3$ \\
$V_{3p}$  &   0 & 1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi/3$ \\
$V_{3n}$  &   -1 &  0 &  -1 &  -$U_{dc}$/6  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$  &   
$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi/3$ \\
$V_{4p}$  &   0 & 1 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &   $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{4n}$  &   -1 & 0 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &   $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{5p}$  &   0 &  0 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{5n}$  &   -1 &  -1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{6p}$  &   1 &  0 &  1 &  $U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{6n}$  &   0 &  -1 &  0 &  $U_{dc}$/6 & - $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{7}$  &   1 &  0 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/2 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/6 \\
$V_{8}$  &   0 &  1 &  -1 &  0 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ &  $\sqrt{3}$ 
$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/2 \\
$V_{9}$  &   -1 &  1 &  0 &  -$U_{dc}$/2 & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{10}$  &   -1 &  0 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/2 & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 7$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{11}$  &   0 &  -1 &  1 &  0 & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ &  $\sqrt{3}$ 
$U_{dc}$/3 & 3$\pi$/2 \\
$V_{12}$  &   1 &  -1 &  0 &  $U_{dc}$/2  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/6$ &  
$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}$/3 & 11$\pi$/6 \\
$V_{13}$  &   1 &  -1 &  -1 &  2$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 &  2 $U_{dc}$/3 & 0 \\
$V_{14}$  &   1 &  1 &  -1 &  $U_{dc}$/3  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$/3 \\
$V_{15}$  &   -1 &  1 &  -1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & $\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 2$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{16}$  &   -1 &  1 &  1 &  -2$U_{dc}$/3  & 0 & 2$U_{dc}$/3 & $\pi$ \\
$V_{17}$  &   -1 &  -1 &  1 &  -$U_{dc}$/3  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 4$\pi$/3 \\
$V_{18}$  &   1 &  -1 &  1 &  $U_{dc}$/3  & -$\sqrt{3}$ $U_{dc}/3$ & 
2$U_{dc}$/3 & 5$\pi$/3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable} 

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

which gives you what you want:

[image]

Comment: Yes  but this is not the problem the problem is that in the code I have written a paragraph that should be displayed after the table but after compiling the paragraph is displayed before the table

Comment: @twimo but you had explictly instructed latex to take the table out of the main document flow and put it in a float so that the two paragraphs are essentially adjacent in the main document text

Comment: and for a figure how can I force it to stay in its place because even if  I use [!ht] the figure as an example is displayed before the table  and for my case I want the figure to be displayed after the table

Comment: @twimo there is no difference between figure and table, the same applies `figure` is only there to take the content _out_ of the document flow. If you have an image and you never want it to move just use `\includegraphics` directly exactly the same as here you use tabular directly.

Comment: Ah now it's clear but here is a complicated case: you have the table environment which is used and the figure environment which isn't used and you want the figure to be displayed after the table and of course there are some paragraphs after the floats. After compiling, the figure will be displayed before the table even if the environment figure isn't used. Normally the figure should appear after the table following what was said before